# Python function for recursively remove data from a list

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas `DataFrame` like following(c2).

```
session   1    2        3         5         8
session                                      
1       NaN  0.8  0.67082  0.676123  0.730297
2       NaN  NaN  0.67082  0.845154  0.912871
3       NaN  NaN      NaN  0.566947  0.612372
5       NaN  NaN      NaN       NaN  0.925820
8       NaN  NaN      NaN       NaN       NaN
```

And another list of values.

```
listofdata = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

I get two list of tuples from the following

```
greater = [(c2.index[i], c2.columns[j]) for i, j in np.argwhere(c2 > 0.8)]
less = [(c2.index[i], c2.columns[j]) for i, j in np.argwhere(c2 < 0.8)]
```

For the 'greater' following are the values I get. [(2, 5), (2, 8), (5, 8)] .I want to find how these 2,5 and 8 will be grouped. To do that First want to find who is the maximum from the 3 groups.

```
b = []
for item in greater:
        b.append( c2.ix[item] )
        maxindex = [(c2.index[i], c2.columns[j]) for i, j in np.argwhere(c2 == max(b))]
```

Since the maximum is (5,8) I want to remove both 5 and 8 from initial 'listofdata'.

```
k = [j for i in maxindex for j in i]
        for i in k:
            try:
                listofdata.remove(i)
            except ValueError:
                pass
```

Now I get listofdata = [1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 9, 10]
Then for the remaining (2, 5), (2, 8) since 5 and 8 has gone from 'listofdata' we can ignore both of them. The same process should be done for 'less' also. Any help in formulating the function.